# Allow requests only from same domain dynamically

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a following domains structure: `local-domain.com`, `staging-domain.com`, `production-domain.com`.

They are have following subdomains respectively:

- `data.local-domain.com`
- `data.staging-domain.com`
- `data.production-domain.com`

**I need to:**

- `data.production-domain.com` will be accessible only from `*.production-domain.com` (and `production-domain.com` of course).
- `data.local-domain.com` will be accessible only from `*.local-domain.com` (and `local-domain.com` of course).
- `data.staging-domain.com` will be accessible only from `*.staging-domain.com` (and `staging-domain.com` of course).

How can I achieve this goal with only one `.htaccess` file, which is in .git and after then shared between servers?

P.S. Sorry for my Engrish

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    local-domain.com/staging-domain.com/production-domain.com   [NC]
```

to detect which domain is one link from.